# Showing value on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a button and when I click it, it dislays a random line from a txt file.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.get('teas.txt', function(data) {
            var teas = data.split('\n');
            random = teas[Math.floor(Math.random() * teas.length)];
            $('p').text(random);
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to show a random line when the page is loaded.

I tried this code and of course it works :

```
$(function() {
    $.get('teas.txt', function(data) {
        var teas = data.split('\n');
        random = teas[Math.floor(Math.random() * teas.length)];
        $('p').text(random);
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.get('teas.txt', function(data) {
            var teas = data.split('\n');
            random = teas[Math.floor(Math.random() * teas.length)];
            $('p').text(random);
        });
    });
});
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a simpler and cleaner way to do it without duplicating the `.get`.

I tried several things without any success...

Any idea?

Comment: Simple, turn the `$.get` into a function, and just call it. If you duplicate code, make a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the code as you showed, just [trigger a click](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) by adding `.trigger('click')` to what you have when the document loads:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.get('teas.txt', function(data) {
            var teas = data.split('\n');
            random = teas[Math.floor(Math.random() * teas.length)];
            $('p').text(random);
        });
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Good code, but you should assign code to button on load, or execute trigger on load

Comment: @SenadMeškin - this is triggering the click on load.

Comment: no, it will not, it will trigger when js is attached, if you put this into header it will never execute, if you put it at the bottom of page it will execute when parsing happens. if you put it in $(document).ready(function(){....}); then it will execute on page load.

Comment: @SenadMeškin - If you look at the OP's code he's using the shorthand document ready handler `$(function() {`. I simply didn't re-include that in my example.

Comment: problem is for someone who has same problem he will just copy your page and will not get same effect.

Comment: @SenadMeškin - lol OK, I'll wrap it in a document ready for you.

Comment: It's not for me, just saying to get better answer solution should be complete.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
    function append_text(){
      $.get('teas.txt', function(data) {
                var teas = data.split('\n');
                random = teas[Math.floor(Math.random() * teas.length)];
                $('p').text(random);
            });
    }    
    $(function() {
            append_text(); 
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
            append_text();
    });
```